# How do I add sdk tools manually to android studio

Tags: sdk, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I downloaded android studio without sdk tools, but I have them already from the eclipse IDE
I want to manually place them where they should be, as when I open android studio it starts downloading the sdk tools automatically, but my data pack is running out, I can't download it!.

Where should I place the sdk tools folder in the android studio files, so that it doesn't attempt to install the sdk tools automatically and just launch the studio directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled the software and added the sdk in install configuration process

Answer (score 1):

you can setup in first setting.. first time you opened android studio..
android studio will ask which sdk you will use

Comment: but mine continued automatically

Comment: After it installed, I opened it and it began downloading the sdk tools automatically