# I already have all the sdk while using Ecllipse . now i am shifting to android studio. how to add sdk to it

Tags: android, android-studio

[found similiar ques but was of no help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27455953/how-do-i-add-sdk-tools-manually-to-android-studio)

Comment: You can use same sdk in both but you want change then replace old sdk

Comment: when you download studio u will get sdk also. do you want to change the sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to File -> project Structure and you can set SDK location there.
You can also set it during Android-studio instalation